# How to approach list of range of values

Tags: python, list

I am trying to decide best way to approach iterating over a list of values to find ranges that encompass other ranges.
i.e. range 8-18 encompasses range 10-14

```
my_range_list = [[1, 1], [2, 8], [3, 16], [4, 16], [15, 25],[14,26]]
# should be the following:
# 3,16 encompasses 4,16 (4-16)
# 3,16 does not encompass 2,8 (2-8)

largest_range_list = []
for my_range in my_range_list:
    my_lowr = my_range[0]
    my_hir = my_range[1]

    new_range_list =[]
    encompassed=0
    for largest_range in largest_range_list:
        largest_lowr = largest_range[0]
        largest_hir = largest_range[1]

        if (my_lowr < largest_lowr) and (my_hir > largest_hir):
            new_range_list.append(my_range)
            encompassed = 1
            break
        if (largest_lowr <= my_lowr) and (largest_hir >= my_hir):
            new_range_list.append(largest_range)
            encompassed = 1
            break
        new_range_list.append(largest_range)
    largest_range_list = new_range_list
    if (not(encompassed == 1)):
        largest_range_list.append(my_range)
print ("largest_range_list=" +  ' '.join(map(str, largest_range_list)))
```

I thought about replacing afterwards but that will not work since `large_range_list` is in constant flux. Also wondering which would be most python way (I come from Perl).

What should I be looking at? Is the starting list good structure or should that be different as well (list of ranges)?

Comment: So do you want that kind of output, for each pair which encompasses other pair?

Comment: Try to implement this with Dictionary. <key, value>, where your keys are ranges pair you want to iterate over and each value is a list of ranges which fit a given condition. <[3,16], list([4, 16], [5, 25])> for example

Comment: Hi Rohit, A new list from my_range_list called large_range_list (what is commented out above, is what the output list should equal.)  So original list could be [[1,4], [3,4], [3,6],[3,8]] outputted list should be [[1,4],[3,8]]. I was going to use large_range_list, but it needs to be constantly updating while traversing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler function to test if a range is included in the range of other:

```
my_ranges = [[1, 1], [2, 8], [3, 16], [4, 16], [15, 25], [14, 26]]

is_encompassed_by = lambda a, b: a != b and (a[0] >= b[0] and a[1] <= b[1])
```

Comparing each range with each of the other ones can be done with permutations:

```
from itertools import permutations

encompassed_ranges = []
for a, b in permutations(my_ranges, 2):
    if a not in encompassed_ranges: # to cut short if it is already there
        if is_encompassed_by(a, b):
            encompassed_ranges.append(a)

not_encompassed_ranges = [r for r in my_ranges if r not in encompassed_ranges]
```

This final list could have duplicates if there were duplicates in the original.

**EDIT**: My first approach is below, but considering the relevant comment of ShadowRanger, I changed it to the solution above

You could approach it using the operations available to work with sets in Python:

```
rng_to_set = lambda rng: set(range(rng[0], rng[1]))

encompasses = lambda a, b: rng_to_set(a).issuperset(rng_to_set(b))
encompassed_by = lambda a, b: rng_to_set(a).issubset(rng_to_set(b))

l = [[1, 1], [2, 8], [3, 16], [4, 16], [5, 25]]
print ( encompasses( l[2] , l[3] ) )  # True
print ( encompassed_by( l[4] , l[2] )) # False
print ( encompassed_by( l[3] , l[2] )) # True
```

Comment: Downside to this approach is that you're doing `O(n)` work, using `O(n)` memory (where `n` is the number of elements in the `range`) creating potentially huge `set`s to test something that requires only `O(1)` work and memory (checking the actual bounds). It's simple in concept, but for non-toy examples, wastes a lot of time.

Comment: In general - using such many lambdas for simple case makes the code hard to maintain and understand. `Simple is better than complex`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your iteration to this:

```
my_range_list = [[1, 1], [2, 8], [3, 16], [4, 16], [5, 25]]
large_range_list = [[1, 1]]

for my_lowr, my_hir in my_range_list:
    for large_lowr, large_hir in large_range_list:
        if (my_lowr <= large_lowr) and (my_hir >= large_hir):
            print("Range ({}, {}) encompasses ({}, {}).".format(
                my_lowr, my_hir, large_lowr, large_hir))
```

I've changed the condition to match your example (`3,16 encompasses 4,16 (4-16)`).

Without change it won't work as the right boundaries overlaps and with original condition (`my_hir > large_hir`) it will reject valid range. Same for the left side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it done all in one go...  I'd do it like this...

```
myRanges   = [(1,1),(2,8),(3,16),(4,16),(5,25)]
testRanges = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,8),(3,16),(5,25)]

[    str((tLo,tHi)) + ' IS enc by '  + str((mLo, mHi)) if (tLo >= mLo and tHi <= mHi)
else str((tLo,tHi)) + ' NOT enc by ' + str((mLo, mHi))
for tLo,tHi in testRanges 
for mLo,mHi in myRanges]
```

depending on your need though...  if you don't need to act on them sequentially (by printing something in this case), this is a cleaner approach.

```
encompassed = [
    ((tLo,tHi),(mLo, mHi))
    for tLo,tHi in testRanges 
    for mLo,mHi in myRanges
    if (tLo >= mLo and tHi <= mHi)]

notEncompassed = [
    ((tLo,tHi),(mLo, mHi))
    for tLo,tHi in testRanges 
    for mLo,mHi in myRanges
    if (tLo < mLo or tHi > mHi)]
```

then to act on them, build a function....

```
def printResults(resultList, printString):
    for t,m in resultList:
        print str(t) + ' ' + printString + ' ' + str(m)
printResults(encompassed, 'encompassed by')

(1, 1) encompassed by (1, 1)
(2, 8) encompassed by (2, 8)
(3, 16) encompassed by (3, 16)
(5, 25) encompassed by (5, 25)
```

I converted your lists of lists into lists of tuples because they were always length two...  but the syntax works fine on lists of lists too.

also, in general list comprehension is the more 'pythonic' way versus nested for loops for simple things...

```
[(x,y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [5,6,7] if x < 3]
```

is preferable to

```
for x in [1,2,3]:
    for y in [5,6,7]:
        if x < 3:
            print (x,y)
```

Comment: The Zen of Python says: "Readability counts."